how to fix wheel building error when installing Box2D
I am attempting to write a Reinforcement learning model using Box2D and TensorFlow in Google Colab. I have a simple one line install command for everything as I've found that Colab breaks whenever I try to do multi line installs, and even the main Gymnasium page has pip install Box2D as the correct way to install it.
Whenever I try to install it, I get this error:
!pip install tensorflow[and-cuda] stable-baselines gym Box2D
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Building wheel for Box2D (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for Box2D
  Running setup.py clean for Box2D
Failed to build Box2D
ERROR: Could not build wheels for Box2D, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Every solution I've found online hasn't worked, and yet all seem to have the same problem. How can I fix it?

Did you try these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76222239/pip-install-gymnasiumbox2d-not-working-on-google-colab

I have found a fix to it, the following code after installing gymnasium worked for me:
!apt-get install build-essential
!apt-get install swig
!apt-get install python-box2d
!pip install gym[box2d]

